# javascript difference between the actual string characters and what console.log shows you

Tags: javascript, alert, console.log

when I assign this value "some \n some more" and console.log() it - the new line character does not come in the output

" This is the first line \n And this is the s e c o n d "
gives
" This is the first line \n And this is the s e c o n d "

or console.log(" This is the first line \n And this is the s e c o n d ")
same

but alert(" This is the first line \n And this is the s e c o n d ") shows the newline
why??

Comment: Without knowing what browser you're referring to, I would say a concerted effort by the developer to keep the log window concise (one line per event/call).

Comment: I've tested in chrome 48, IE11 and FireFox 44.02. They all break the lines at \n.

Comment: no console display is WYSIWYG, it's a formatted output that can be as deceptive as it is pretty. even further, `alert()` is now higher-level in most browsers, for ex: `alert("Hello\n\tWorld")` doesn't indent the 2nd line on ch/win but does on FF/win...

Comment: @Prabhas What does `alert("ab\u000Ac")` render ?

Comment: @Stack0verflow: if there is more stuff being logged, console can alter it's display. ex: `console.log(["line1\nline2"])`

Answer (score 0):

\n is the JavaScript escape code for a new line character. Whenever that string is included in a string that will be parsed by the JavaScript engine, the code produces a new line. When you consume that code in an alert(), the JS engine parses that and sends it to the alert with the new line character in the string. But, when you send it to the console, the JS engine is bypassed and **the browser's particular implementation of their console is used**.

A more concise example is this:

```
    alert("This is a \n test");
    someParagraphElement.innerHTML = "This is a \n test";
```

In the second line of code, no new line is produced because that line sends the string to the HTML parser, where \n is just another white space character to be ignored.

Comment: They do not. alert is implement via the window object and console is proprietary.

Comment: `window.hasOwnProperty("console")`

Comment: @ScottMarcus _"In the second line of code, no new line is produced because that line sends the string to the HTML parser, where \n is just another white space character to be ignored."_ Note, `pre` and `textarea` element , `css` `white-space:pre` at other elements  render `\n` as newline character

Comment: I stand corrected, but all others do not and the only reason those two work is because that character means something in that context. In the context of the console, that char code does not.

Comment: @dandavis What you are missing is that when Chrome adds a console object to window, it's proprietary, unlike alert, or XmlHttpRequest or any of the other standards and de facto standards.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, but that's not what we are discussing.

Comment: im just failing  to understand the distinction you're making between `alert` and `console` in terms of origin; both are proprietary and both are de facto standards, both are implemented by the host.

Comment: console is not a de facto standard - alert is.  There is no browser that doesn't support alert and/or implements it differently than any other. This is not true with console.

Comment: as i noted above, `alert("Hello\n\tWorld")` doesn't appear the same everywhere, so `alert` is no more "standard" than `console`. in some browsers, long text in `alert` is truncated. in some browsers, you can select and copy alert()ed text, in others you cannot. also, all browsers support `console`; any that don't aren't supported themselves...

Comment: @ScottMarcus Would `alert("ab\u000Ac")` render newline character at all browsers ?

Comment: It appears so, if I'm reading the spec. correctly http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/